# jquery show hide

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

i try to show and hide divs on click but something isnt going wel

can someone have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JedaDesign/R4ng5/11/)

what i want is:

- when people arrive on the page they see the content of the first "news" div
- when clicking on a other anchor they will see the corresponding content instead of the previous
- append a style to the active anchor link

I have searched whole this site , and well the result is in the Fiddle

can someone help me with this

Comment: And what do you have problems with? Hiding the elements on click seems to work well...

Comment: just set the second and third news div in the beginning to display:none;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to hide all `.news` except the first one?

http://jsfiddle.net/R4ng5/13/

```
$(".news:not(:first)").hide();
```

And if you want to style the active link:
http://jsfiddle.net/R4ng5/14/

```
$(list).children('li:first').children('a').addClass('active');
$('#sidebar a').click(function() {
    var i = $('#sidebar a').index($(this));
    $('.news').hide();
    $(".news:eq(" + i + ")").show();
    $('#sidebar a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```